# Proving Norm of a linear functional is $ \| f \| _{p} = max \{ |a_1|,...|a_n|\}$ if $p=1$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $f$ be a linear functional on $\mathbb{K^{n}}$. Then $$ f(x) = a_1 x(1)+ ... + a_n x(n)$$ for some $a_i \in \mathbb{K}$ and all $x= (x(1),...,x(n)) \in \mathbb{K^{n}}$.
Consider p-norm on $\mathbb{K^{n}}$ where $1 \leq p \leq \infty$. Then we have to prove that.
$$ \| f \| _{p} = max \{ |a_1|,...|a_n|\}$$ if $p=1$.
I have managed to solve the first part of the problem but need a (small) hi t on the second part where I have to find norm of operator.
I would appreciate it if someone could give me a hint on how to go on about solving it.
Thank you.

Comment: Write down the definition of $\|f\|$. Seems applicable.

Comment: I don't understand what you meant. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, 
$$
\|f\|_1 = \sup_{\|\boldsymbol  x\| = 1} |f(\boldsymbol x)|_{\mathbb K} = |f(\boldsymbol x)|.
$$
By definition of $\|\cdot\|_p$ in $\mathbb K^n$, 
$$
\|\boldsymbol x\| = (|x_1|^p+|x_2|^p + \cdots + |x_n|^p)^{1/p}.
$$
Thus,
$$
\|f\|_1 = \sup_{\sum_1^n |x_j|=1} |a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + \cdots + a_n x_n|. 
$$
By triangle inequality, 
$$
|a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + \cdots + a_n x_n| \leqslant |a_1 x_1| +| a_2 x_2 |+ \cdots + |a_n x_n| \leqslant \max\{|a_j|\}_1^n (|x_1|+|x_2|+\cdots +|x_n|) = \max \{|a_j|\}_1^n.
$$
The equal sign could be attained: if $\max\{|a_j|\} =| a_k|$, then take $\boldsymbol e_k$ [the $k$-th standard basis vector in $\mathbb K^n$] the $=$ would hold. So $\max \{|a_j|\}$ is truly the supremum. Hence the equation.

Comment: I'm sorry but I guess I'm dumb enough to not figure out why the equality holds, could you explain that too?

Comment: @clear WLOG, suppose $|a_1| \geqslant| a_2| \geqslant \cdots \geqslant |\a_n|$. Let $\boldsymbol x=(1, 0, 0, \ldots, 0)$, then the quantity $|a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + \cdots + a_n x_n| = |a_1|$ which is the greatest $|a_j|$.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. Thanks a lot :) and have a nice day!

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help!